# Provider tag makes screen go blank in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, provider

When I remove the `<Provider>` tag I get the output, when I put that tag screen goes blank.

index.js file is below

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

app.js file is below

```
function App() {
  return (
  <div className="App"> 
     App Home
  </div>
  );
}
```

Please let me know what to do?

Comment: Provider requires store object, I think that could be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-redux Provider expects to receive a "store" prop. You can check the docs: https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider